# Fetch data from mysql with xiaomi device

Tags: android, mysql

I'm developing an app that fetchs data from mysql database. When I run the app with my samsung device, data will be fetched from database and showing up but if I run the app with my xiaomi device, nothing comes from server. here are my permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem wasn't about samsung or xiaomi. It was about Android version of device. Android 9 and upper versions dont allow php mysql connection. We need to add,

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

to Manifest file and it works.